# SQL different between two dates inside group by

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-difference

I have this table -

```
----------------------------------------------
ID  | user   | eventID   | type   | timestamp
----------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:30:00
2   | 1      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:31:00
3   | 1      | 1         | 9      | 2019-02-08 15:31:30
4   | 2      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:32:00
5   | 2      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:32:45
6   | 3      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:33:00
7   | 3      | 1         | 9      | 2019-02-08 15:34:00
8   | 3      | 2         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:35:00
9   | 3      | 2         | 9      | 2019-02-08 15:36:00
```

I'm trying to find the time difference between the type 3 and type 9 for each event, for each user.

For example, the output for this table would be -

```
----------------------------------------------
ID  | user   | eventID   | timeDifference in sec
----------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | 1         | 30
2   | 3      | 1         | 60
3   | 3      | 2         | 60
```

As you can see, each user can have multiple events, and different users can also have the same event. Some users and events have both the types, some don't. There could be multiple type 3 and type 9 events but I want the difference between the ones closest to each other. And type 9 always happens after type 3. I also have a separate column that has a different ID for type 9 events, if that's helpful. So I'm trying to find the time difference between these 2 types for each event, for each user.

How do I go about doing this?

Edit - I forgot to mention that there can be multiple pairs of type 3 and type 9 events for each event, for each user. SO I want the difference of all these pairs, that are next to each other, not just one difference per group by.

For this table -

```
----------------------------------------------
ID  | user   | eventID   | type   | timestamp
----------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:30:00
2   | 1      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:31:00
3   | 1      | 1         | 9      | 2019-02-08 15:31:30
4   | 2      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:32:00
5   | 2      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:32:45
6   | 3      | 1         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:33:00
7   | 3      | 1         | 9      | 2019-02-08 15:34:00
8   | 3      | 2         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:35:00
9   | 3      | 2         | 9      | 2019-02-08 15:36:00
10  | 3      | 2         | 3      | 2019-02-08 15:37:00
11  | 3      | 2         | 9      | 2019-02-08 15:37:40
```

Output would be -

```
----------------------------------------------
ID  | user   | eventID   | timeDifference in sec
----------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | 1         | 30
2   | 3      | 1         | 60
3   | 3      | 2         | 60
4   | 3      | 2         | 40
```

edit - I asked a difference question with my edit. The original question here was answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question:

```
select user, eventid,
       (to_seconds(min(case when type = 9 then timestamp end)),
        to_seconds(max(case when type = 3 then timestamp end))
       ) as diff_seconds
from t
group by user, eventid;
```

This returns the difference between the earliest "9" timestamp and the latest "3" timestamp.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that there can be multiple pairs of the types in the group. I've added another example in my question to clarify that. Can you help me modify this query to include that condition?

Comment: @ajyvardan . . . That significantly changes the question and you should not have made the change.  Your original question explicitly stated "Type 9 always happens after type 3", which is no longer true in the revised.  If you have a *different* question, it should be asked as a *new* question.

Comment: Type 9 does always happen after type 3, but there can be multiple occurrences of that inside the event. I can ask a different question if that is a big problem.

Comment: I'm sorry @gordon. I'll delete the question and ask again.

Comment: @ajyvardan . . . You can leave this question . . . edit back to its original form.  Then ask another question.  In that question, note what version of MySQL you are using.